# utf8 problem when pulling data from postgresql

Tags: node.js, windows, postgresql, psql

hello developer friends!!

I am using nodejs for the backend.

I am usin POSTGREsql for the database.

**problem**:
When I pull data from the database, Russian alphabets seem complicated.

**question**:
how can i solve this problem?
any ideas?

**NOTE**:
my connection.

```
 const Pool = require('pg').Pool
    

const pool = new Pool({
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    database: process.env.DATABASE,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    client_encoding:'utf8'
})
```

Comment: What is your `server_encoding`? If you cast one of the "complicated" columns to `bytea`, how does it look?

Comment: my database's `server_encoding` is **utf8**, `client_encoding`  is **WIN1251**.  from `SHOW SERVER_ENCODING` and `SHOW CLIENT_ENCODING`.